# How to rename multiple columns in pandas by changing one letter in column names?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, loops, rename

I have

```
In:  df.columns

Out: Index([''Category_tl22_p1',
       'Category_tl22_p2', 'Category_tl22_p3', 'Category_tl22_p4',
       'Category_tl22_p5', 'Category_tl22_p6', 'Category_tl22_p7',
       'Category_tl4_p1', 'Category_tl4_p2', 'Category_tl4_p3',
       'Category_tl4_p4', 'Category_tl61_p1', 'Category_tl61_p2',
       'Category_tl61_p3', 'Category_tl91_p1', 'Category_tl91_p2',
       'Category_tl91_p3', 'Category_tl91_p4', 'Category_tl91_p5',
       'Category_tl91_p6', 'Category_tl91_p7'],  dtype='object')
```

and I want to change one letter in the column names, 'tl' in the names for 'fl'.

I have tried this but it is very tedious.. are there better alternatives?

```
df.rename(columns={'Category_tl22_p1':'Category_fl22_p1', 'Category_tl22_p2':'Category_fl22_p2','Category_tl22_p3':'Category_fl22_p3','Category_tl22_p4':'Category_fl22_p4',}......, inplace=True)
```

Comment: ``df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("tl","fl")`` ?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use : ``df.rename(lambda x: x.replace("tl", "fl"), axis="columns")``

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I have other columns there as well.. this is a subset of my whole df. hopefully it will work anyway.